# On column relation with 2 table

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I have 3 table `user` , `admin` , `ticket`

A ticket can sent by `user` or by `admin` so I need to add relation between `ticket` and `admin` ,`ticket` and `user`

I think the solution is create `ticket` table like this

`ticket ( id , content , usertype , userid )` and `usertype` is `ENUM('admin','user')`

So if `usertype = admin`, `userid` refer to `admin` table and if `userype = user` , `userid` refer to `user` table.

Now I have 2 question

1.My way to create tables is right ?

2.If it's right how I add `foreign key` ?

I'm using `MySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right.
You need to make a disjoint (like inheritance in OOP)

`ticket` should be represented by 3 tables alone:

1-`ticket (id, content)` where `id` is a primary key

2-`ticket_user (id, userid)`, here both attributes are Primary keys and `userid` is a foreign key to `user` table and `id` is foreign pointing to `ticket` table

3-`ticket_admin (id, adminid)` , same as above with `adminid` pointing to the `admin` table

I am answering based on the Database Design course I take at college and we haven't used MySQL so I can't tell you exactly how to implement that.